# Can I programmatically pass a prop to children components in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want children of my component to have class prefix. Apparently, we can access chidren via this.props.children, but it's not recommended to modify it's value. But anyway it feels unnatural to hardcode it, so maybe you could come up with an idea?

```
<Aside className="right">
  <Timer className="right" />
  <LoginFrame className="right" buttonTitle="this.state.buttonTitle" />
</Aside>
```

For example, I want my Timer to have className="right__timer", where __timer postfix is specified in the component itself

Comment: Which "component itself" are you referring to?

Comment: Also, you probably meant `buttonTitle={this.state.buttonTitle}`?

Comment: @AKX In Timer render function. It just returns h1 with a specific content and attribute of className

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yeah, It had a string value but I wanted to post it here as dynamic solution, but forgot to switch the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Timer className="right" />
```

will not add a `class` to an HTML element alone, that needs taken care of within `Timer` itself, or within one of its children, where `className` eventually gets added to a native HTML element, not a React component.

For example, for Timer you may have -

```
const Timer = ({ className }) => {
   return (
       <div className={`${className}__timer`}>...</div>
   )
}
```

and usage -

```
<Timer className="right" />
```

edit...

you can use something like -

```
{React.Children.map(children, child => (
   React.cloneElement(child, {className: child.props.className.concat(className)})
))}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I want className="right" proprety to be placed automatically for every child of my Aside component

Comment: ah ok, see edit, may need a bit of work but along those lines

Comment: yes, thath's what I was trying to achieve. The problem is that it's unusual to modify children
p.s oh wait

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't pay attention, only noticed a children variable

Comment: yea kind of, though if this is CSS related, I would argue you shouldnt need to append `right` everywhere, as the above solution would only work to the first level of children

Comment: Well, is that a good practice? I would accept it as a solution, but the main reason I asked this question is that I am trying to avoid anti-patterns

Comment: if its for CSS, you would just put `right` at the parent level, and then structure your CSS selector to target children belonging to `right` class, e.g. all `<p>` tags belonging to `right` class would be `.right p`

Comment: I'm currently learning BEM.. Let there be a convention that I will not dive deeper than 2 levels of nesting :)

Comment: Oh I see, I only will pass Components if that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

1. Context
2. Component

**#1 Context**

#1.1 Create a context

```
const ClassContext = React.createContext({
  className: "right"
});
```

#1.2 The Children elements are the consumer

```
const { className } = useContext(ClassContext);
// prefix this to your component
```

#1.3 The Main app wraps the context around the consumers

```
<Aside className="right">
    <ClassContext.Provider value={{className: "right"}}>
        <Timer />
        <LoginFrame buttonTitle="this.state.buttonTitle" />
    </ClassContext.Provider>
</Aside>
```

**#2 Component**

Create an Aside Component that adds the Classname Prop

```
const Aside = (props) => {
    const {children, ...all} = props;
    return (
        <div {...all}>
            {React.Children.map(children, child => (
                React.cloneElement(child, {className: props.className})
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: sheesh, that escalated quickly

Comment: Thanks for these awesome answers. I think Context solution looks better since it's a compositional solution, so anyone who's reading this code could understand immediately what's going on there. But is it ok to use context for this purpose?

Comment: Oh, there's a problem. Component solution fits all requirements since the idea was to not change the implementation of the children. So Component solution does everything as intended.

Comment: Wait a moment, I guess we are changing all props of our child when we map them this way. Since we just replace Child word with the component name. We will basically lose all other props

Comment: You are string manipulating css classes, I don't really like that pattern. If you want to use component based styling you shouldn't do it with class name manipulation and rather set flags via properties. If you use global styling you should use cascading styles in your css files (`.right > .timer {}`)

Comment: I also like this technique, but I've recently heard about BEM naming pattern, which is better for css. By BEM convention, we use prefixes like that for every element that is a child of another container. I don't really know if this is an apparent thing or is it even a reliable technique. 
Visit https://en.bem.info/methodology/css for more information about BEM

Comment: Even if you want to stick to BEM (which feels little outdated to me nowadays) you shouldn't use it via string manipulation but rather with CSS Modules or similar libraries. A good read is here: https://medium.com/trabe/a-comprehensive-guide-to-using-bem-with-react-14d00c199e0d

Comment: I updated the code to keep all other props given to the component.

Comment: If this is outdated, do you recommend to write CSS selectors normally? Or are there any other conventions?

Comment: It looks like children still lose their props. 
If we pass <Timer iamprop="prop" /> as a child, map will change it to <Timer className="right" /> and drop the rest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235550/discussion-between-florian-bauer-and-yuriy-kirel).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
const prefix = "right";

.
.
.


<Aside className={`${prefix}`}>
  <Timer className={`${prefix}_timer1`} />
  <LoginFrame className={`${prefix}_timer2`} buttonTitle="this.state.buttonTitle" />
</Aside>
```

Comment: This is basically a hardcode. Imagine you want to create an Aside component, and every child has to put it's className as a prefix. Imagine putting thousand of Timer into this component. Let's agree. putting this template strings wouldn't be convenient

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's preventing you from modifying that prop internally before you pass it on:

```
function Timer(props) {
  if(props.className) props.className += "__timer";
  return <h1 {...props}>...</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse, I can change it internally. The problem is that I want to modify props of my Aside component children before rendering them. My Timer component can't know by itself what className is developer intending to pass without a specified className

Comment: Then I'd use React context to pass the, well, rendering context around...

Comment: I wouldn't assume that context is something that is used only to prepend className to my components :(